# Javascript broke on Stackoverflow

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow

It seems a bunch of javascript is not working on the main stackoverflow site.

The arrow next to my name won't drop down the summary numbers.

I can't click on add comment on a question.

Basically broke.

Since I started to see `rev 2013.11.7.1139`

Please give us the tasty `rev 2013.11.7.1618` which is on meta, it seems to work.

**n.b.** - I'm using Chrome

Comment: Works On My Machine™ (IE 10 on Win RT).

Comment: @michaelb958 - do you have 1139?

Comment: Yep - `rev 2013.11.7.1139`.

Comment: No repo - Chrome 31.0.1650.39 beta on Linux Mint.

Comment: No repro, no errors: Linux Firefox 25.0, Chrome 30.0.1599.114, Chrome 32.0.1685.0 dev. Check your console!

Comment: Still broken for me, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204627/stylesheets-broken-on-main-stackoverflow-com-site.  Do you have stylesheets or is only the scripting broken?

Comment: Try loading http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js & tell me what you see.

Comment: oh - and if you get something *crazy*, take a screenshot.

Comment: … namely a CAPTCHA.

Comment: @Potatoswatter No JS for robots, robot.

Comment: @Shog9 - Sorry I went to bed -- I'm at work now and it seems fine.