# CAPTCHAs are intermittently blocking CDN content

Tags: bug, captcha, cdn, cloudflare

I get HTTP errors for various resources, and no styles or scripts are applied, which effectively makes the whole site unusable.

Meta does seem to be working fine, though.

Edit: Here's a log from Firefox Console. The relevant requests appear to be returning 403 Forbidden.

```
[10:28:39.766] GET http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269438/is-there-a-way-to-call-member-function-without-or-operator/19827813# [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 917ms]
[10:28:40.929] GET http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 680ms]
[10:28:40.932] GET http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=e3d47b73fa12 [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 612ms]
[10:28:40.935] GET http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=87e1657c9db8 [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 605ms]
[10:28:41.401] GET http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=e3d47b73fa12 [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 347ms]
[10:28:41.753] GET http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=87e1657c9db8 [HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden 237ms]
```

Edit 2: It happened again. This time I screenshotted everything. The CAPTCHA actually does not appear to be the usual one with men dressed as robots. I had to scale the page down a bit drastically to fit onto one screenshot.

[image: Unstyled page]

[image: Console log]

[image: CAPTCHA]

I'm posting this update a bit in the blind because the same error prevents those images from loading. Let me know if they weren't uploaded. Meta still shows no other symptoms.

Comment: Works On My Machine™ (IE 10 on Win RT, SO rev 2013.11.7.1139). (Although I do get a 404 when I load that page manually.)

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm in Asia-Pacific. And the same thing has happened on a few occasions before.

Comment: That URL isn't used to style the sites and shouldn't even be loaded - what happens if you try to load http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=87e1657c9db8 ?

Comment: @Shog9 I get a CAPTCHA page. That could be the problem.

Comment: After proving that I'm not a bot, it gave me the codez :D

Comment: whaaaa...? Post a screenshot. Of the *entire* browser window showing the captcha.

Comment: @Shog9 Sorry, now I'm apparently authenticated. The main site works again and the requests return 304 Not Modified. The CAPTCHA was nothing special, just the usual intermediate page.

Comment: May be firewall blocked in your side..

Comment: @Sam See above, the CAPTCHA servlet was misconfigured.

Comment: Lest the link be lost, someone on the other side of the world had the same problem at the same time: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204626/javascript-broke-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Nothing in the logs - not the normal ones anyway. You're hitting the CDN for that, and not hitting the webservers is kinda to be expected. Of course, getting the normal captcha page *would* produce a log entry - but then, there shouldn't be any way to get a captcha when hitting the CDN. I kinda wonder if you don't have something on your network messing with you...

Comment: @Shog9 As I noted in the moderator flag I just added, the other guy had the same problem at the same time on the other side of the world (New York is literally 12 time zones from here). There must be some path from the GET request for CSS to the CAPTCHA servlet, and there's nothing my network could be doing "wrong," it's just a different entry point into the CDN.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - This is the first time I've been called "the other guy"

Comment: @Potatoswatter Investigating re your flag, going to take a little time though - hang tight.

Comment: @TimPost Let me know…

Comment: @Potatoswatter Nick Craver has to do some serious log sawing, which he's going to try to do later today or tomorrow morning. This might be something to do with the request _itself_ and the security layer on the CDN not liking it - we'll find out. I removed the tag for now.

Comment: @TimPost OK, good luck. The problem seems to have resolved itself on my end now without submitting a CAPTCHA.

Comment: It happened to me on quite a few occasions when the CDN is down too. Whatever happen to graceful degradation???

Comment: @TimPost It's happening again…

Comment: @Potatoswatter It happened to _me_ yesterday, it's at the CDN it seems, we're trying to figure out what's going on

Comment: Cmon… folks? I saw the same error from CloudFlare on resources from another site outside the SE network. If it's beyond your control, maybe file a complaint?

Comment: It's happening again… same CloudFlare captcha.

Comment: Just as an aside, as for Meta doing fine: Meta is not using the CDN for JavaScript and CSS. (Instead, Meta loads if from `/content/`.)

Comment: In case it helps: I also see the CSS missing every now and then (maybe once a month?), but I never investigated and a refresh or two always fixed it. I'm on a static IP from Amsterdam, and I'm quite sure my system is not misbehaving. (Could be something different, of course.)

Comment: This is still occurring. The CDN server's pages are protected by CloudFlare CAPTCHA.