# CloudFlare CAPTCHAs are blocking CDN content

Tags: bug, captcha, cdn

When I changed my avatar on [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com) a few days ago, it briefly displayed at the top, then after a few minutes disappeared from the toolbar.

[image]

Later it disappeared from my questions and profile as well. Further inspection revealed that it was hidden behind an HTTP 403 forbidden result with a CAPTCHA, courtesy CloudFlare. Answering the CAPTCHA restores functionality, for now.

This is the same problem as [CAPTCHAs are intermittently blocking CDN content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204627/stylesheets-broken-on-main-stackoverflow-com-site). Randomly knocking out resources is unacceptable for a CDN. Please address this.

Comment: I've been having weird rendering issues like this all day. How did you check to see if it's behind a 403? Is that easily accessible from chrome dev console?

Comment: @Emracool Just open the browser's traffic monitor and reload the page.

Comment: I'm going to advise you change the title on the other post and I can start a bounty on it. I'm getting the same problem. But, as it stands, this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Emracool I already put a bounty on the other one. I don't know why it's not mentioned on the page, but it cost me 500 rep last December 19. This problem has been known for years. Something else is needed to motivate the admins.

Comment: I'll post a bounty on that one if you change the title - but this is still a duplicate.